# Can I "insert" a backspace character into a buffer?

Tags: text-editing

I'm trying to tail the output from a command into a buffer, and I just learned that the command occasionally uses long strings of `^H` to backspace over previous lines.

Like, the command stdout will first send `this line is temporary` then send `^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^Hpermanent` next, so the result in my terminal just looks like `this line is permanent`.

Is there a simple way to recreate this effect in a buffer?  If at all possible I'd really prefer to avoid iterating over the characters in the output stream and replacing each `^H` with a call to `delete-char`.

I've tried variations on `(insert ?^H)` but no joy.  `^H` appears in the buffer at point, but I want the character before point to be deleted.

Comment: How about `C-q C-h`, AKA `(insert ?\C-h)`, AKA `(insert 8)`? See [`(emacs) Inserting Text`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html).

Comment: Edited to clarify what happens when I try these insert-based solutions, and why that does t work for me

Comment: If you want to interpret carriage returns, backspaces, etc. I think the easiest way is to use `comint-output-filter`, specifically its subroutine `comint-carriage-motion`. See the function `shell-command`, for example.

Comment: Ah, bummer.  Looks like that function does the thing I was hoping to avoid -- it runs over the string transforming control characters into function calls.  Eh, so it goes.  Mind writing up an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: In that case it's not at all clear just what behavior you are requesting.